# Python: remove duplicates in a dictionary list based on 2 values,

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have this dictionaries list:

```
[{'emailAddress':'user1@test.com','role':'writer','displayName':'USER1','type':'user','resultRole':'writer'},
{'emailAddress':'user2@test.com','role':'owner','displayName':'USER2','type':'user','resultRole':'owner'},
{'emailAddress':'user1@test.com','role':'writer','displayName':'USER1','type':'user','resultRole':'multiplex'},
{'emailAddress':'user2@test.com','role':'owner','displayName':'USER2','type':'user','resultRole':'owner'},
{'emailAddress':'user3@test.com','role':'commenter','displayName':'USER3','type':'user','resultRole':'multiplex'}]
```

I want to remove the duplicate dictionaries in the list based on the user's email address (good so far), the problem I have is that if the user is duplicated and the "resultRole" key has the value "multiplex", it remains and the other duplicate is removed.

the result i want:

```
[{'emailAddress':'user2@test.com','role':'owner','displayName':'USER2','type':'user','resultRole':'owner'},
{'emailAddress':'user1@test.com','role':'writer','displayName':'USER1','type':'user','resultRole':'multiplex'},
{'emailAddress':'user3@test.com','role':'commenter','displayName':'USER3','type':'user','resultRole':'multiplex'}]
```

how could i do it?

At the moment I only remove the duplicates with this code:

```
seen = set()
permissionsUsers_list = []
for d in docResults:
    t = tuple(d.items())
    if t[1] not in seen:
        seen.add(t[1]) 
        permissionsUsers_list.append(d)
```

Comment: What is the criteria for which duplicate should be kept?

Comment: Why are you converting `d.items()` into a tuple? Use `d['emailAddress']`

Comment: I don't see how you're getting `multiplex` for `user1@test.com`. The result should contain the first occurrence of the email, which has `resultRole = writer`.

Comment: You could do this in two passes.  First, add only the dicts where `resultRole=multiplex`.  Then, add any remaining dicts with unique email addresses.

Comment: Instead of a set, use a dictionary whose keys are the emails and values are the dictionaries from the original list. If the email is already in the dictionary, compare the resultRole to see if you should replace it or not.

Comment: @Barmar In case of a duplicate email address, the one with `resultRole=multiplex` should be kept, which isn't necessarily the first one in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the initial list in a fashion that users with `multiplex` are in the last place. Then remove the duplicates using a dictionary.

For example (`lst` is your initial list):

```py
out = list(
    {
        d["emailAddress"]: d
        for d in sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d["resultRole"] == "multiplex")
    }.values()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "emailAddress": "user1@test.com",
        "role": "writer",
        "displayName": "USER1",
        "type": "user",
        "resultRole": "multiplex",
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "user2@test.com",
        "role": "owner",
        "displayName": "USER2",
        "type": "user",
        "resultRole": "owner",
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "user3@test.com",
        "role": "commenter",
        "displayName": "USER3",
        "type": "user",
        "resultRole": "multiplex",
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` instead of a `set`, and retrieve the list with `list(a_dict.values())`:

```py
from pprint import pprint

D = [{'emailAddress': 'user1@test.com', 'role': 'writer', 'displayName': 'USER1', 'type': 'user',
      'resultRole': 'writer'},
     {'emailAddress': 'user2@test.com', 'role': 'owner', 'displayName': 'USER2', 'type': 'user', 'resultRole': 'owner'},
     {'emailAddress': 'user1@test.com', 'role': 'writer', 'displayName': 'USER1', 'type': 'user',
      'resultRole': 'multiplex'},
     {'emailAddress': 'user2@test.com', 'role': 'owner', 'displayName': 'USER2', 'type': 'user', 'resultRole': 'owner'},
     {'emailAddress': 'user3@test.com', 'role': 'commenter', 'displayName': 'USER3', 'type': 'user',
      'resultRole': 'multiplex'}]

email_to_dict = {}

for the_dct in D:
    emale = the_dct['emailAddress']

    if the_dct['resultRole'] == 'multiplex':
        email_to_dict[emale] = the_dct
    elif emale not in email_to_dict:
        email_to_dict[emale] = the_dct

pprint(list(email_to_dict.values()))
```

Result:

```
[{'displayName': 'USER1',
  'emailAddress': 'user1@test.com',
  'resultRole': 'multiplex',
  'role': 'writer',
  'type': 'user'},
 {'displayName': 'USER2',
  'emailAddress': 'user2@test.com',
  'resultRole': 'owner',
  'role': 'owner',
  'type': 'user'},
 {'displayName': 'USER3',
  'emailAddress': 'user3@test.com',
  'resultRole': 'multiplex',
  'role': 'commenter',
  'type': 'user'}]
```